# Cast close and reopen votes page instructions wrong?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, privileges-page

I noticed, that in the description page for the [cast-close privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) at the very bottom it mentions several alternatives to closing. One of the alternatives is

> If the question is a duplicate, post a comment with a link to the original.

I thought, this was replaced/amended by flagging a post as `duplicate`. Shouldn't the description be changed to reflect that?

Answer (score 2):

I think that those directives are more geared towards situations when you are out of close votes.  That way, if you leave a comment, others will be inclined to vote to close as a duplicate.

When you are able to vote to close, any flags you put towards duplicates, etc (except for spam and those with specific reasons written in) are converted to close votes.

Comment: But the part starts with: "If you don't have enough reputation to cast close votes.."

Comment: @nfechner I see what you are saying, but I think it's more directed towards the second half of that statement of running out of close votes.  I don't think it's trying to be the official word on flagging, but perhaps it should be edited out.

Comment: @nfechner - If you have enough reputation to cast a close vote, the comment and link will be added automatically.